# How to imitate margin collapse in CSS flexbox with different sized magins?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I know that flexbox does not have margin collapse.
I know that there are some workarounds, but non that I found is working in my case.
The problem is, that I have margins of different sizes.

### Example

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 30px;
  background-color: #abc;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

h1 {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  margin 36px 0;
}

h2 {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  margin 24px 0;
}

p {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  margin 16px 0;
}

.box {
  background-color: #eee;
  margin: 36px 0;
  flex-basis: calc((100% - 36px) / 2);
}
```

```html
<h1>How to make this margins collapse?</h1>
<p>
  When display is set to flex, margins are not collapsing.
  The problem is, that the margins, that I have, are of different sizes.
</p>
<div class="box">
  A box with some content.
  The margin should be 36px.
  The margin to the elements above and below should "collapse".
</div>
<div class="box">
  A box with some content.
  The margin should be 36px.
  The margin to the elements above and below should "collapse".
</div>
<div class="box">
  A box with some content.
  The margin should be 36px.
  The margin to the elements above and below should "collapse".
</div>
<h2>Headline 2</h2>
<p>Rem nihil praesentium incidunt quis, deleniti dignissimos! Eveniet delectus quidem, minima reiciendis sapiente quos hic laudantium exercitationem blanditiis molestias? Perferendis dolorum adipisci quidem non sit voluptatum vel doloremque eum quisquam!</p>
<div class="box">
  A box with some content.
  The margin should be 36px.
  The margin to the elements above and below should "collapse".
</div>
```

### No Solution

1. I can not just set the maring half the size, because that would not add up to the correct margin.
2. I can not take advantage of the sibling selector because I do not know the order of the HTML elements by now.

### Options

1. It is not set in stone to use flexbox, but it would do the job for now.
2. If this turns out to be to complicated, I will “cheat” and change the margins.

Comment: If everything is 100% width, why do you need flex?

Comment: That is just for this example.

Comment: better give a more realistic example because in this case flexbox is not needed. Block element will do the job

Comment: A more realistic example won't change the question. If this may not be possible with flexbox, fine. But the example is perfectly fine to illustrate the question.

Comment: *A more realistic example won't change the question* --> it will change our motivation. Personnaly I won't even think about a solution considering the actual code because there is no need to use flexbox. A more realistic example where flexbox is really needed will make things look different for us (I have been answering more than 5000 so my comment was on purpose).

Comment: Given the example above, I also don't see why you are trying to force this with flexbox when there are other methods designed for this where flexbox is not.

Comment: I tried to use float, but I can not control if a box "lands" on the left or on the right side. Thus I can't set the margin left and right. But float does not allow a gap between the boxes. If there are other *methods desdinged for this*, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I came to the conclusion, that this is not possible with flexbox.